# Session State Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, session-state, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle Application Express. I am running into what I think is a session state issue. So here is my issue.

1. I have two machines, with two different web browsers.
2. Machine 1 sort on column 1 and machine 2 is sort of column 2
3. Machine 1 I sort on column 3
4. I refresh the page on Machine 2 and the sort moves to column 3

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have two different sessions?  Or are you using the same session ID in the two browsers (presumably by cutting and pasting a URL)?  Are you talking about a regular report?  An interactive report?  Something else?  What determines how the report is sorted?  Is there a user setting or an application item that controls that?

Comment: @justinCave  I have two different session IDs going on within the two browsers. I cant cut and paste because I am psychically accessing the APEX page on a separate machine. This was built originally as a classic report, but then became an interactive report. I use the default sort functionality built in APEX. I attempted to create processes where it clears the session state of the current application but it does not work. Not sure if I am doing it correctly. I have it firing on a new instance.

Comment: What authentication scheme do you use?

Comment: Do you have Server Caching of the application, page or report set to Cache by User ?

Comment: @Tom I do not use any authentication. It is not needed

Comment: @Cristian_I How do I find out if it is set to Server Caching. I did not set any caching on the page or user.

Comment: Usually the default is set to disabled server caching but just to be sure go into the properties of the page and of the report (the place where you edit the page title or the report query) and check that property Server Caching is set to disabled.

Comment: @cristian_I I checked my report region and CACHING was set to not cached already. I do not see a property called Server Caching. This is Apex 4.2 i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any kind of authentication then apex saves column sorting "globally". ie apex doesn't know for who it should save sorting.

For example if you had authentication in your application every users sorting preferences would be saved in apex.

If you wish to reset sorting on every page load read into these docs

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25309/api.htm#CHDIBDEC

Also look at this explanation about preferences

> Managing User Preferences
>
> You can use preferences to store values for a **specific Application Express user** across distinct sessions. Once set, these preferences can be removed programmatically or manually. You can set user preferences by creating a page process, by the calculation of a preference Item Source Value, or programmatically by using a PL/SQL API.

Source :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e12512/aadm_mg_sessions.htm

Comment: This seems to be the answer, but I'm not quite sure where I place remove_sort_preference. I would like it done per session state.

Comment: You do it as an ON LOAD Process before header. You can do it on the page that has the report on you can do it with global page process .

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That worked, however I ran into a small issue. Whenever I click on a column to sort and click next for the next set of rows, the sort reverses. I attempted to set the default sort on each column, but it keeps changing. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Do you have partial page refresh set to : YES on your report?

Comment: I actually have that set as No because when it is set to yes and I click next to grab the next set of rows, I run into a pagination error where it asks to reset it.

Comment: You will need to solve that problem. Beacuse when it's set to NO : It refreshes the page with every pagination click. Which means that your onload process will trigger everytime ,meaning your preferences will reset on every click on your pagination.